# JS helper link for a different action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using this

```
              echo $this->Js->submit("Send", array(
                'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
                'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
                'update'=>'#success'                            
                    ));
```

This is in index.ctp and onclick it goes to index action in the controller. But I want it to go to a different action. How'd I do that.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it wokring

need a url array for a different action

```
 echo $this->Js->submit("Send", array(
'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
'update'=>'#success',
'url' => array(
     'action' => 'pp'
         ),                     
));
```